# Advice (debug php on OSX Mountain Lion with MAMP)

Tags: php, mamp

I need to find a way of debug my localhost php experiences.
When coding, and since I'm a begginer most of times I make errors that return an Internal Server Error.

Is there any way of having some plugin or something that teels me where is the error?
Per example something like: Error on line 54 or something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not possible with php, as it is not compiled.
Better is to have a debugger that lets you step through your code line by line and shows you the state of your application. In PHP-world this module is called xdebug
http://xdebug.org/

Answer (score 0):

I see you use MAMP, but in case its of interest to you, here's a set of instructions that uses OSX Mountain Lion's native Apache2 and XDebug together with MacGDBp and a Safari extension called [XDebug Helper](http://dokimay.com/index.php/mac-osx/56-configuring-xdebug-on-osx-mountain-lion).